# Ferramenta Montagem de software

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa, mas desconheço as tecnologias que podem existir ou recursos que podem ser utizados para isto.
Portanto, solicito indicações de keyworks e apontamento de tecnologias,frameworks que atende complementamente ou parcialmente.

"Procuro um software ou ferramenta, onde através da definição de um diagrama,
possibilite visualmente indicar a finalidade de um grupo de elementos, de modo que gere a codificação complementar"

Enfim, algum recurso que seje capaz de fazer a conexão dos relacionamentos entre os elementos indicados pelo usuario. Gerando o funcionalidades CRUD, DAO, dentre outras.

Observação que não estou referindo a regra de negocio, que varia conforme objetivo do produto final.

Answer (score 1):

Uma ferramenta que possa ser util é o [postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest). Está ferramenta transforma seu banco de dados PostgreSQL em uma API, dessa forma bastaria somente construir o frontend do projeto e conecta-la ao postgrest.

Comment: Está ferramenta é totalmente REST, você não precisaria construir uma linha de código backend.